# Elastic search sort result not showing in SearchResponse

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I wanted to get the last records whose sequenceStatus is "OB ORDER COMPLETE", so I used matchQuery and sort the timestamp with `DESC` order. Then I return the first result.
After printing the first 10  results, I found the first result is not the last records as I expected. It is the first record. How can I get the last record?
This is the code:

```
String[] includeFields = new String[] {"eventTimestamp"};
String[] excludeFields = new String[] {"logEvent","testId","orderId","marketId"};
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("sequenceStatus", "OB ORDER COMPLETE")).sort("eventTimestamp", SortOrder.DESC).fetchSource(includeFields,excludeFields);
searchSourceBuilder.size(20);
searchReq.source(searchSourceBuilder);
try {
SearchResponse searchResp=client.search(searchReq);
SearchHit[] results = searchResp.getHits().getHits();
queryResultPrint(results);
String eventTimestamp= searchResp.getHits().getAt(0).getSourceAsMap().get("eventTimestamp").toString();
return eventTimestamp;
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

The results:

{"eventTimestamp":"2018-05-14 19:52:22.221184000"}

{"eventTimestamp":"2018-05-14 19:52:22.221645000"}

{"eventTimestamp":"2018-05-14 19:52:22.222064000"}

{"eventTimestamp":"2018-05-14 19:52:22.222445000"}

{"eventTimestamp":"2018-05-14 19:52:22.222880000"}
......

Note: queryResultPrint(results) is code to print searchResponse.

Comment: Do you get the same result with an ascending sort ?

Comment: I am  new to ES but shouldn't it be just `sort("_timestamp", SortOrder.DESC)` instead of `eventTimestamp` ?

Comment: Yes. I get the same results when I use SortOrder.ASC.

Comment: @Alex, I am new to ES too. what is the _timestamp? The last record in my problem means the record with latest eventTimestamp so I sorted by "eventTimestamp"

Comment: default name for that field is `_timestamp` I think. just try.

Comment: @Alex, Using "_timestamp" gave me an exception:"No mapping found for [_timestamp] in order to sort on"

Comment: I don't see any loop in your code, you are getting just first hit from query results here. So how did you get all your outputs?

Comment: for(SearchHit hit : results) {
          String sourceAsString = hit.getSourceAsString();
          if (sourceAsString != null) {
              System.out.println(sourceAsString);
          }
      }

Comment: where is the part when you define `searchReq` var?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing relation between your `searchSourceBuilder` and `searchReq`. At least I can't see that in code fragment you've posted.

From my point of view you should have another line of code before getting the response:

```
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("sequenceStatus", "OB ORDER COMPLETE")).sort("eventTimestamp", SortOrder.DESC).fetchSource(includeFields,excludeFields);
/* binding source searchSourceBuilder to searchReq */
searchReq.source(searchSourceBuilder);
/* */
SearchResponse searchResp=client.search(searchReq);
```

As I said I am new to ES, and can be wrong

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had that line. I just forgot to put it in my question.Otherwise, I won't be able to get any results.

Comment: So probably you have something else? Are you sure that you've shared everything with us?

Comment: I just edited my question and share the complete code.